# string replacement using xargs

Tags: shell, sed, makefile, xargs

I am trying to collect file path and timestamp for each file under a certain directory(which is passed as an argument) in makefile

So, it goes like this.

```
TIMESTAMP_LOG := timestamp.log
TARGET_ROOT := ../../out/root

define collect-timestamp
  $(shell find $(1) | xargs -lfn sh -c 'echo -n fn"," >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG); stat -c %Y fn >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG)')
endef

all:
    $(call collect-timestamp, $(TARGET_ROOT))
```

If I run this, i would the get whole file path and timestamp as below 
ex) ../../out/root/bin/ls,133030303

but I want to get rid of "../../out/root" in file path.(passing as an argument if possible)

I thought I could do this using sed or shell script(see below) but apparently I am stuck.  I tried:

```
$(shell find $(1) | xargs -Ifn sh -c 'echo -n ${fn##$(1)}"," >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG); stat -c %Y fn >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG)')  

$(shell find $(1) | xargs -Ifn sh -c 'sed 's/fn//g' >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG); stat -c %Y fn >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG)')
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: $(shell find $(1) | xargs -Ifn sh -c 'echo -n ${fn##$(1)}"," >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG); stat -c %Y fn >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG)')

Comment: $(shell find $(1) | xargs -Ifn sh -c 'sed 's/fn//g' >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG); stat -c %Y fn >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG)')

I've tried above and couple more but I don't think they were right

Comment: Can you put those in the question?  It's easier to see/edit/understand there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `find`, you don't need `xargs` in most cases.

The following should work:

`find $(1) -exec stat -c "%n,%Y" {} \; | sed 's#$(1)\/##'`

Note that I use $(1) as both parameter to `find` and in `sed` substitution command.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
find $(1) | xargs stat -c %Y >> $(TIMESTAMP_LOG)
```